# How to Mimic youtube bottom navigation behavior with android navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I'm trying to achieve navigation experience identical to youtube's bottom navigation using android navigation component. It seems like there is no easy way of doing it, at least not built into the library.

I've already tried playing with `NavOptions` when navigating to the desired location.

```
navController.navigate(it.itemId, null, NavOptions.Builder()
.setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
.setPopUpTo(it.itemId, false)
.setLaunchSingleTop(true)
.build())
```

**Assuming I have fragments A, B, C and D, and navigation:**

A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> B

**I expect the back stack to look like:**

`|B|
|A|
|D|
|C|
|A|`

**Back navigation to look like:**

B -> A -> D -> C -> A

**When it's actually resulting in:**

`|B|
|A|`

**And:**

B -> A

Eliminating duplicates while maintaining proper home fragment navigation.
A is the home fragment, hence the first and last fragment the user will see.

Anyone? Thanks